# Html Video tag controls not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

The following code works fine in Google Chrome but in Firefox the controls are frozen--I click on play but still the video doesn't play. None of the controls work.

Same code works fine when I try in a separate html file different video same video type (MP4).

```html
<video id="loadedVideo" style="width:1340px;height:830px;" controls="">\
  <source src="url?file=file-4c369dc4cf165ef426c42502e088bee8e403c1d67096e608d4b5227b6fa71d12ff5977a3f66d4e3f5732e8ef78bbec3d">
</video>
```

Comment: What does the browser console say? I am guessing that's probably a problem with a video _format_ Firefox doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code with my own video and it works make sure to read about browser support from this site [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com);
and ensure about the video itself;

Comment: Yes it works when I try too. This code doesn't work only in my web app.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the url in source?